# issue in display Date in different format with one string value android

Tags: java, android, date, date-format, simpledateformat

Hello friends i have one string value for date like "2015-02-04" and below is my code

```
Date todaysDate = new java.util.Date("2015-02-07");
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
SimpleDateFormat df2 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
SimpleDateFormat df3 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
SimpleDateFormat df4 = new SimpleDateFormat("MM dd, yyyy");
SimpleDateFormat df5 = new SimpleDateFormat("E, MMM dd yyyy");
SimpleDateFormat df6 = new SimpleDateFormat("E, MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss");


try
{
    //format() method Formats a Date into a date/time string. 
    String testDateString = df.format(todaysDate);
    System.out.println("String in dd/MM/yyyy format is: " + testDateString);
    String str2 = df2.format(todaysDate);
    System.out.println("String in dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss format is: " + str2);
    String str3 = df3.format(todaysDate);
    System.out.println("String in dd-MMM-yyyy format is: " + str3);
    String str4 = df4.format(todaysDate);
    System.out.println("String in MM dd, yyyy format is: " + str4);
    String str5 = df5.format(todaysDate);
    System.out.println("String in E, MMM dd yyyy format is: " + str5);
    String str6 = df6.format(todaysDate);
    System.out.println("String in E, E, MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss format is: " + str6);

}
catch (Exception ex ){
    System.out.println(ex);
}
```

my when i run above code i gives me error like

```
02-05 16:34:28.288: E/AndroidRuntime(27931): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
02-05 16:34:28.288: E/AndroidRuntime(27931):    at java.util.Date.parse(Date.java:437)
02-05 16:34:28.288: E/AndroidRuntime(27931):    at java.util.Date.<init>(Date.java:149)
02-05 16:34:28.288: E/AndroidRuntime(27931):    at com.example.paginationdemo.Demp.onCreate(Demp.java:33)
```

at line **Date todaysDate = new java.util.Date("2015-02-07");**

any idea how can i solve it?

Comment: Note that as it's the first line of your posted code that is failing, the rest of it is somewhat pointless - it might make sense to include one or two formats to show what your aim is, but you don't need 6 of them...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple: don't use the [deprecated `new Date(String)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Date.html#Date(java.lang.String)) constructor. Instead, create a `SimpleDateFormat` with the right format, and use the `parse` method.

```
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.US);
format.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("etc/UTC"));
Date date = format.parse("2015-02-07");
```

*Always* look at compiler warnings such as when you're using deprecated members. They're usually deprecated for a reason!